# How to gather statistical information from Exchange Server?

Tags: .net, rest, api, email, exchangewebservices

I need a windows service which could gather various statistics from Exchange server and return them as api response. The statistics cover things like mailbox, connections, address book, etc. What are the best alternatives for me in terms of:

(1) How to implement the service

(2) How to retrieve those statistical information from Exchange Server

I have taken a look at EWS Managed API but not sure if it could the purpose. Any advice and insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

EWS is a Mailbox API so it would be something that you would use when you want to access Mailbox data as a user or Delegated users. It doesn't provide any statistics or Administrative information on a Mailbox

> > mailbox, connections, address book

These are administrative statistics so you need to use the admin API which for Exchange is the Exchange Management Shell. You can use the EMS from your managed code like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff326159(v=exchg.140).aspx .

You would need to use cmdlets such as Get-MailboxStatistics to get Mailbox sizes etc